# How to use "USE ?" with CURSOR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, database-cursor

I found a great [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/) about how to use a cursor:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200) 

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name 
    FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = 'SELECT ' + '''' + @DB_Name + '''' + ', SF.filename, SF.size FROM sys.sysfiles SF'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

The problem is that when I execute it it always returns the same `filename` and `size`. The article explains that it's because we have removed `USE ?`.

So let's put it back:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200) 

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name 
    FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = ' USE ? SELECT ' + '''' + @DB_Name + '''' + ', SF.filename, SF.size FROM sys.sysfiles SF'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

But SQL Server throws this error for every database:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '?'

Exactly 5 times which is the number of databases I have.

How to use this cursor?

Comment: Don't write your own cursor for this, the problems have been solved long ago, e.g.: https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql and the author wrote about it in a link in the comment: https://mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the @DB_Name variable instead of a `?`:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(200) 
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases 

OPEN database_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
     SELECT @Command = ' USE ' + @DB_Name + ' SELECT ' + '''' + @DB_Name + '''' + ', SF.filename, SF.size FROM sys.sysfiles SF'
     EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

The chosen answer works, but it does not protect you from SQL injection. If someone has the ability to create a database on this system, they could - for example - perhaps under the guise of testing, QA, or through a UI that lets users create databases - create a database named `tempdb; SELECT name,salary FROM Accounting.dbo.Employees;` and gain access to sensitive information (or, worse, do damage!) in a database they don't currently have access to, and this path is only made possible by the dynamic SQL's execution context.

Also you should not be using deprecated compatibility views like `sysdatabases` and `sysfiles`, and you should protect yourself from offline and otherwise inaccessible databases which will cause your process to grind to a halt. A couple of other minor things like your strings need to be longer (to account for potentially longer database names), should always be `nvarchar` because people can name their database  or `[]`, etc.

And finally you need to avoid the problem caused by using a default cursor, which can lead to databases being arbitrarily skipped. This is already solved by the procedure I mentioned in my comment [(`sp_ineachdb`)](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql) and the background Mr. Bertrand wrote [in the referenced article](https://mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/).

If you really don't want to use an open source procedure that already does all the things you need and protects you from many issues you might not even know about yet, then try:

```
DECLARE @dbname  nvarchar(128), 
        @command nvarchar(1000) = N'SELECT 
            DB_NAME(), [filename] = physical_name, size 
          FROM sys.database_files;',
        @context nvarchar(1000), 
        @c       cursor;

SET @c = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0;

OPEN @c;
FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @context = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  EXEC @context @command;  
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;
END 
-- also don't need to close/deallocate @local cursor.
```

And if you want them to all come back in the same dataset instead of having one dataset per database, you can:

```
DECLARE @dbname  nvarchar(128), 
        @command nvarchar(1000) = N'SELECT 
            DB_NAME(), [filename] = physical_name, size 
          FROM sys.database_files;',
        @context nvarchar(1000), 
        @c       cursor;

SET @c = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR 
  SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0;

OPEN @c;
FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;

CREATE TABLE #t (db nvarchar(128), [filename] nvarchar(260), size int);

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  SET @context = QUOTENAME(@dbname) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
  INSERT #t EXEC @context @command;  
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @dbname;
END 
-- also don't need to close/deallocate @local cursor.

SELECT db, [filename], size FROM #t;
```

But really, go grab [`sp_ineachdb`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql). With that procedure installed, your code immediately becomes this simple:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_ineachdb @command = N'SELECT DB_NAME(),
  [filename] = physical_name, size FROM sys.database_files;';
```

Comment: This is beautiful, perfect, I love it. Especially all the results in the same dataset. I cannot install `sp_ineachdb` bacause for complience we cannot install anything on the customer database.

Comment: I have discovered with grief that I can run your query on SQL Server on prem but it doesn't work on Azure SQL Database. If you run something on `master` you cannot iterate through other databases, you need a new connectin for each database. 
And also from an Azure SQL Database you cannot query `master` or any other database on the same server.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani if you need to support multiple databases on the same server in Azure SQL Database, not exactly a common scenario, you should tell people that in the question.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani It also begs the question, how does the accepted answer possibly work on Azure SQL Database? Sounds like you should be asking two separate questions because even the code in your question can’t possibly run there either.

Comment: I was actually testing this on prem and both my questions and your answers apply on prem. Is only later on that I tested on Azure. But both question and answer are still valid.