# How to create a temptable for this query

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I would like to create a temptable that will hold the result of this query:

```sql
set @sql = 'use ' + @dbname + '; select db_name() , name from sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0 and type_desc = ''USER_TABLE'' '
    exec (@sql)
```

Here is the full query I have:

```
declare @minx int = 0
declare @maxx int = (select max(id) from #DBS)
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
declare @dbname varchar (130)
declare @count int 

Select * 
 
from #DBS

while (@count is not null
       and @count <= @maxx)
begin
    select @dbname = dbname
    from #DBS where id = @count
    print 'id = ' + convert (varchar, @count) + ' dbname = ' + @dbname
    set @sql = 'use ' + @dbname + '; select db_name() , name from sys.tables where is_ms_shipped = 0 and type_desc = ''USER_TABLE'' '
    exec (@sql)
    set @count = @count + 1
    break
end;
```

I have tried so many things and always getting error messages.

Anybody could give me an insight?

Comment: To start with, your `DECLARE` statements are in single quotes, so that's going to generate multiple errors. I think you need to *explain* what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hi @Larnu, My maingoal is to have atemptable where I can store the date from the query I mentioned on the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you populate `#DBS` but:

```
CREATE TABLE #tables(db sysname, table_name sysname);

DECLARE @dbs     cursor, 
        @context nvarchar(1000), 
        @sql     nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = N'INSERT #tables(db, table_name)
  SELECT DB_NAME(), name
    FROM sys.tables 
    WHERE type = ''U'' AND is_ms_shipped = 0;';

SET @dbs = CURSOR FOR SELECT QUOTENAME(dbname)
  + N'.sys.sp_executesql' FROM #DBS;

OPEN @dbs;
FETCH NEXT FROM @dbs INTO @context;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  EXECUTE @context @sql;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @dbs INTO @context;
END  

SELECT db, table_name FROM #tables;
```

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73989385/20091109).